# Table with Non Identifying Keys

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-schema

My company was using this model to manage the inventory

[Model 1 http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/6024/modeltest2.jpg](http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/6024/modeltest2.jpg)

But i was having problems because in this month we bought some plastic bags with a different price, expiration date on the same warehouse.

So now i changed the model to this.

[Model 1 http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/8416/modeltest.jpg](http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/8416/modeltest.jpg)

My question is if this is ok.. it is working but is the first time i create a table with only no Primary key.

Example of Data:

```
PRODUCT        WAREHOUSE   Quantity   Price  Expiration_Date
PLASTIC BAG    NEW YORK    20         1.20$  12-10-2013
PLASTIC BAG    NEW YORK    130        1.50$  21-12-2015
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it's OK. In Sales, Warehouse systems you can't save all products with different expiration date in Product Table, because there would be a lot records for each product. But usually you need to save them in "Item_Ledger_Entry" Table where would be all Transactions of Sales or Purcahse.

You using one same Product just with different expiration Date. I think you don't need at all Priamrey Key in `Product has warehouseKey`

Comment: I add price to this inventory because they need a valued inventory report... so i need the specific price of each quantity. And this Warehouse supplies the production department and then used to calculate the final cost of the process. In this scenario you think the same would work?

Comment: You everything done correctly like in Navision. It doesn't matter PrimaryKey for you at all, i understand that for you just need to connect `Product has warehouseKey` with product and warehouse and when get each product specific Cost and Price in report. That you can do and without PrimaryKey. Very good logic you using with Quantyti and Price in  `Product has warehouseKey`.

Answer (score 1):

One problem with this, specific to MySQL and InnoDB storage, is that InnoDB will silently create an extra 6-byte integer internally to serve as a surrogate primary key.  Also, queries against any InnoDB table are more efficient if you can do them via the primary key.  So it's to your advantage to define a primary key (or unique key) if possible.

If the combination of columns Product_ID, Warehouse_ID aren't sufficient to uniquely identify every row, then you could add a third column to distinguish between duplicates.  For example, Stock_ID or something.

Comment: If i add a third column to distinguish i would have to add for Price and also Expiration Date and it would be a compound key of 4. That's why i was trying to find other ways... You think the compound key of 4 would work better??

Comment: I meant add a *new* column to serve as the third in the primary key.  Some column to identify which batch of inventory this row represents.

Comment: Ok i get it. I'm going to try that now.